# Get output of document.write in scrapy

Tags: javascript, python, scrapy

I am scraping a website that has the following structure:

```
<td colspan="1">
    <font class="spy14">
        91.240.61.217
        <script type="text/javascript">document.write("<font class=spy2>:<\/font>"+(One2NineSix^Four3Eight)+(One2NineSix^Four3Eight)+(One2NineSix^Four3Eight)+(Zero9EightSeven^Nine6Six))</script>
</td>
```

When you see it on the page, this looks like this:

```
91.240.61.217:6660
```

But when I try to scrape it, I find myself unable to get the ":6660" part as that's generated by the JS script above.

How do I get that part of the HTML? Here is my current code:

```
val = Selector(response)
ip = val.xpath('//tr[@class="spy1xx"]/td[1]/font').extract_first()
```

The JS code may seem nonsensical but the page also has this script in it:

```
eval(function(p,r,o,x,y,s){y=function(c){return(c<r?'':y(parseInt(c/r)))+((c=c%r)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(o--){s[y(o)]=x[o]||y(o)}x=[function(y){return s[y]}];y=function(){return'\\w+'};o=1};while(o--){if(x[o]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+y(o)+'\\b','g'),x[o])}}return p}('p=B^C;m=G^I;h=F^E;r=H^J;f=2;l=K^u;e=5;c=4;n=8;t=v^w;j=A^z;g=y^x;k=1;d=D^O;b=T^V;s=6;a=3;o=7;i=0;q=9;L=i^j;Q=k^g;P=f^b;M=a^m;N=c^d;R=e^l;S=s^r;X=o^p;W=n^t;U=q^h;',60,60,'^^^^^^^^^^Four^Seven4Seven^Five^Nine3Three^One^Zero^OneTwoZero^Seven9Four^Two^Nine6Six^Three^TwoOneNine^Eight5One^Seven^Eight^NineThreeTwo^Nine^Four3Eight^Six^Seven0Five^8090^5462^88^808^12035^3129^11286^10218^8909^6038^8888^7449^6689^3320^80^443^2546^Zero9EightSeven^Nine1SixNine^SixThreeFiveFive^8000^Nine7OneZero^Seven0FourOne^ZeroSixTwoEight^One2NineSix^9273^Six2ZeroFour^8118^Eight9SevenThree^FiveFourThreeTwo'.split('\u005e'),0,{}))
```

So it does actually print out ":6660". This I tested.

Is there a way to either

a) get the output of their script as displayed on the page by document.write

or

b) scrape the JS code and run it locally through Python, somehow

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to Guillaume's answer would be using `js2py` inside your spider to execute the JS code:

```
>>> import js2py
>>> js = r"eval(function(p,r,o,x,y,s){y=function(c){return(c<r?'':y(parseInt(c/r)))+((c=c%r)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(o--){s[y(o)]=x[o]||y(o)}x=[function(y){return s[y]}];y=function(){return'\\w+'};o=1};while(o--){if(x[o]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+y(o)+'\\b','g'),x[o])}}return p}('p=B^C;m=G^I;h=F^E;r=H^J;f=2;l=K^u;e=5;c=4;n=8;t=v^w;j=A^z;g=y^x;k=1;d=D^O;b=T^V;s=6;a=3;o=7;i=0;q=9;L=i^j;Q=k^g;P=f^b;M=a^m;N=c^d;R=e^l;S=s^r;X=o^p;W=n^t;U=q^h;',60,60,'^^^^^^^^^^Four^Seven4Seven^Five^Nine3Three^One^Zero^OneTwoZero^Seven9Four^Two^Nine6Six^Three^TwoOneNine^Eight5One^Seven^Eight^NineThreeTwo^Nine^Four3Eight^Six^Seven0Five^8090^5462^88^808^12035^3129^11286^10218^8909^6038^8888^7449^6689^3320^80^443^2546^Zero9EightSeven^Nine1SixNine^SixThreeFiveFive^8000^Nine7OneZero^Seven0FourOne^ZeroSixTwoEight^One2NineSix^9273^Six2ZeroFour^8118^Eight9SevenThree^FiveFourThreeTwo'.split('\u005e'),0,{}))"
>>> js2py.eval_js(js)
16296
```

Js2Py: https://github.com/PiotrDabkowski/Js2Py

As for extracting the JS code from the page, I'm afraid you need to share more details about the page itself so that we can help you figure out how to do it.

Comment: I like the js2py option, but the result you got there doesn't appear right (when I ran the JS code manually I got the correct 6660). Any idea why that is? As for extracting the JS from the page, that I can handle.

Comment: @jovan Running the same `eval()` in my browser's console returned the same value as js2py. Are we running the same JS snippet?

Comment: Well, yes, but you're missing this whole part of the code: `document.write("<font class=spy2>:<\/font>"+(One2NineSix^Four3Eight)+(One2NineSix^Four3Eight)+(One2NineSix^Four3Eight)+(Zero9EightSeven^Nine6Six))` so I'm not sure how it evaluates to anything :)

Answer (score 0):

You can install a Javascript interpreter such as [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/) and call it from Python.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

js = r"eval(function(p,r,o,x,y,s){y=function(c){return(c<r?'':y(parseInt(c/r)))+((c=c%r)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(o--){s[y(o)]=x[o]||y(o)}x=[function(y){return s[y]}];y=function(){return'\\w+'};o=1};while(o--){if(x[o]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+y(o)+'\\b','g'),x[o])}}return p}('p=B^C;m=G^I;h=F^E;r=H^J;f=2;l=K^u;e=5;c=4;n=8;t=v^w;j=A^z;g=y^x;k=1;d=D^O;b=T^V;s=6;a=3;o=7;i=0;q=9;L=i^j;Q=k^g;P=f^b;M=a^m;N=c^d;R=e^l;S=s^r;X=o^p;W=n^t;U=q^h;',60,60,'^^^^^^^^^^Four^Seven4Seven^Five^Nine3Three^One^Zero^OneTwoZero^Seven9Four^Two^Nine6Six^Three^TwoOneNine^Eight5One^Seven^Eight^NineThreeTwo^Nine^Four3Eight^Six^Seven0Five^8090^5462^88^808^12035^3129^11286^10218^8909^6038^8888^7449^6689^3320^80^443^2546^Zero9EightSeven^Nine1SixNine^SixThreeFiveFive^8000^Nine7OneZero^Seven0FourOne^ZeroSixTwoEight^One2NineSix^9273^Six2ZeroFour^8118^Eight9SevenThree^FiveFourThreeTwo'.split('\u005e'),0,{}))"

p = Popen(['node', '-p', js], stdout=PIPE)
output, _ = p.communicate()
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
b'16296\n'
```